# How Do I Specify a Keyword for Dash with Doxygen?

Tags: macos, documentation, doxygen

I am using Doxygen for generating documentation for my project, which generates docsets that work almost perfectly with [dash](http://kapeli.com).

What I want to know is how to set the search keyword in dash; the default is "unknown:"

[image: Dash Docsets]

What do I need to change so that it reads something other than "unknown:".  Can I change this in Doxygen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm Dash's developer. Dash uses the DocSetPlatformFamily key in the Info.plist file inside the docset to determine the default keyword. Unfortunately, Doxygen has no option as far as I'm aware to set this value. I will contact the Doxygen team and ask them to add this option. Feel free to do the same.

For now, my best recommendation would be to write a post-generation script that would add the required key in the Info.plist file (it's just a text file).

For example, this should work:

```
perl -pi -w -e "s/<\/dict>/<key>DocSetPlatformFamily<\/key><string>__DESIRED KEYWORD__<\/string><key>DashDocSetFamily<\/key><string>doxy<\/string><\/dict>/s" Info.plist
```

Note: I've also added a "DashDocSetFamily" entry with a value of "doxy". This will cause Dash to handle the docset as a Doxygen-generated one and display the filterable table of contents.

In case you haven't found them already, here are some recommended settings for generating a Doxygen docset for use in Dash:

```
SEARCHENGINE           = NO
DISABLE_INDEX          = YES
GENERATE_TREEVIEW      = NO
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your prompt response.  Dash is awesome - keep up the good work!